# WebProxy with Credential connect to Proxy with no Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, proxy, windows-ce

Currently i am developing a Window CE application. The application is require to connect to the web through proxy.

I tend to depend on IE as if IE is able to connect, C# webproxy should do the same as well.

I know that Proxy with Authentication, we will require to use C# webproxy with credential to connect. It will only connect when the username and password in credential is entered correctly.

But if connecting to Proxy with no Authentication, and the WebProxy that we entered is with credential, will it still connect successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it and it seem that WebProxy itself will ignore the credential if the connecting proxy doesn't need authentication.

In other word, webproxy will decide if it will use the credential or not when connecting.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the proxy being used (how the proxy internally handles authentication).
Best way to find out is to do a quick test.

Comment: Understood. Will test it to find out the behaviour.

Comment: Gr8. Hope this was helpful